# i have written something like a getint function. Does anyone have suggestions for improvement?

Tags: c++, integer

first of all i would like to confess that i am still quite a beginner.
I started learning c about half a year ago and started with c++ a few days ago, so please do not be too harsh with me :).

you probably know the following problem:
You have written a small program that runs in your console and want the user to enter something.
of course, it is very inconvenient when the user types the wrong things, so we have to prepare for any small child hacking like a madman on the keyboard.

Most functions wait for a valid input, which results in the problem that nasty line breaks occur when the user only presses the enter key.

the problem is also normally easy to solve under linux:
read a character with getchar, determined the position of the cursor with the ANSI escape sequences and provided the whole thing with a do while loop.

BUT: i was not able to find a simple function to read in numbers in the same elegant way.
The function must be able to read in numbers, but also be able to prevent line breaks.
to achieve this, I used getchar and store the characters in a char array, whose indices I then convert to the corresponding numbers, which I then add to the actual number.

But maybe there is an easier way? or you have ideas how to optimize the function?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TheGameHeaders.h"

#define CLEAR_LINE printf("\033[K")
#define POSITION(Ze, Sp) printf("\033[%d;%dH", Ze, Sp)
#define CLEAR printf("\033[2J")


int getint(int pos_ze, int pos_sp, int qntty_of_incs)
{   
    int i = 0;
    char fake_nbr;
    char fake_nbrs[qntty_of_incs];

    int real_nbr = 0;
    int real_nbrs[qntty_of_incs];


    do
    {
        POSITION(pos_ze, pos_sp);
        while((fake_nbr = getchar()) != '\n')
        {
            if(fake_nbr == '0' || fake_nbr == '1' || fake_nbr == '2' || fake_nbr == '3' || fake_nbr == '4' || fake_nbr == '5' || fake_nbr == '6' || fake_nbr == '7' || fake_nbr == '8' || fake_nbr == '9')
            {
                if(i <= (qntty_of_incs-=1))
                {
                    fake_nbrs[i] = fake_nbr;
                    i++;
                    qntty_of_incs++;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    while(i < 1);

    for(int a = 0; a < i; a++)
    {
        fake_nbrs[a] -= '0';
        real_nbrs[a] = fake_nbrs[a];
    }

    int i_fix = i;
    int i_fix_2 = i-=1;

    for(int a = 0; a < i_fix; a++)
    {
        i = i_fix_2;
        real_nbrs[a] *= pow(10, i-=a);
    }

    for(int a = 0; a < i_fix; a++)
    {
        real_nbr += real_nbrs[a];
    }

    return real_nbr;
}
```

Comment: user input with numbers is also just characters, hence I got lost starting with your "BUT...". Assuming this is complete and working code, you might try at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (make sure your question meets their rules before posting), while asking for a code review is considered opinion-based and offtopic here

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're just looking for a better way to get integers, and if that's true, then yes, there is a much better way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    int x;
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";
        std::cin >> x;
        if (std::cin.good()) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Not an Integer" << std::endl;
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        }
    }
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

You can use the standard input stream `cin` to read an integer directly without any mess. You can check if the input was valid using `cin.good`. You have to clear the buffer if you want to try again.

Comment: but this code has the same problem: if you just press enter you create a line break.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Because `cin` is waiting to pull an integer out of the buffer. Seeing a leading newline isn't illegal, so it keeps waiting. If you want the user to be allowed to press enter to skip it, you'll need to read in a string from the user, then convert that to an int. I can update my answer for that if you like.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you're saying. You want to hide the new line entirely. Personally I think you're trying to solve a non-issue. No one is going to be offended by that. But if you really want to fix it, you could use a state machine, which would simplify your model a bit, I might try to work on that.